# TextBox.Text property is not assigned in UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, textbox

My UserControl code is below, I have one TextBox in UserControl and would like to access TextBox.Text property from web page.

UcUserForm user control is inserted in myform.aspx web page.

On myform.aspx PageLoad I set value for textBox like this

```
ucUserForm.TbFirstName.Text = "Tomas";
```

Everything works fine. When web page is loaded I see name inside textbox. Then I change value from Tomas to Jonas.

On myform.aspx ButtonClick I am trying to read value

```
var mynewname = ucUserForm.TbFirstName.Text;
```

despite that name is changed from Tomas to Jonas in TextBox on web page I still get the old name Tomas. Can't understand where is the problem.

UserControl code behind

```
  public partial class UcUserForm: System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {


        public TextBox TbFirstName
        {
            get { return tbFirstName; }

        }

}
```

UserControl web page

```
  <asp:TextBox  ID="tbFirstName" autocomplete="off"  MaxLength="25" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Registration user control code in default.aspx

```
<%@ Register Src="ucUserForm.ascx" TagName="ucUserForm" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<uc1:ucUserForm ID="ucUserForm" runat="server" />
```

Comment: remove the "set" accessor: it's harmful

Comment: Removed. But the problem still persist.

Comment: can you show how you add the user control to the page ? Is the viewstate enabled ?*

Comment: @SteveB I added user control registration code. Viewstate is set to default - enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
           ucUserForm.TbFirstName.Text = "Tomas";
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You set it every time you load the page. Try in Init stage.

Similar to this

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ucUserForm.TbFirstName.Text = "Tomas";
    }
```

The Init just happens once in the Page's life cycle

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx